# Are these natural actions of $SL(3,2)$ over $\{1,...,7\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let be $G=SL(3,2)$. I know that 
$\alpha=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
\end{array}\right),$
$\beta=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right),$
$\gamma=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
\end{array}\right)$ are a set of generators for $G$.
Now I consider two actions  ${\varphi}_1$ and ${\varphi}_2$.

The first permutation representation is defined as follows:

$\alpha\longmapsto \bar{\alpha}=(73)(62)$, 
$\;\beta\longmapsto \bar{\beta}=(35)(24)$,
$\;\gamma\longmapsto \bar{\gamma}=(56)(21)$

The second permutation representation is:

$\alpha\longmapsto \bar{\alpha}=(46)(57)$, 
$\;\beta\longmapsto \bar{\beta}=(24)(53)$,
$\;\gamma\longmapsto \bar{\gamma}=(12)(65)$

Is it true that the first action is the transitive action of $G$ on the seven points of the proiective plane over ${F}_2$ (field with two element) and the second one is the transitive action on the seven lines of the proiective plane?
How can I prove that? Thanks!

Comment: For either claim, you need to exhibit a bijection of $\{1,\ldots,7\}$ with the set of points or lines. At any rate, thes actions are not natural because there is too much arbitrary in them

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: thanks for your replay. So the first action is the transitive action of $G$ on the seven points because I can construct the isomorphism you mentioned by enumerating the points, is it right?